# OpenJPA:JPQL vs native query

Tags: sql, orm, jpql, openjpa, nativequery

I am using OpenJPA in my work.
Sometimes I have to use JPQL and sometimes I have to use native query(em.createNativQuery).

I am witnessing a big issue with native query. I have to provide schema name too.

Like for JPQL I can write:

```
em.createQuery("Select e from Entity_name e").getResultList();
```

But in case of native query I need to do:

```
em.createNativeQuery("Select e from SCHEMANAME.Table_name e").getResultList()
```

Why is it so?And isn't this wrong behaviour as schema name may vary with time.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the following property in your configuration.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="SCHEMANAME"/>
```

If you use both JPQL and native queries, try to add the actual entity as follows.

**e.g** `Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MAG", Magazine.class);`

Otherwise you might face data inconsistency issues like dirty reads, lost updates .etc

**UPDATE**

```
Query createNativeQuery(java.lang.String sqlString,
                        java.lang.Class resultClass)
```

> Create an instance of Query for executing a native SQL query.
>
> Parameters: sqlString - a native SQL query string
>
> resultClass - the class of the resulting instance(s)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mandroid : Did you try passing the instance class as shown in the **example** of my answer?

Comment: Hi Tharindu, I didn't do that. Actually my SQL string has 2 different tables.How to deal in such a case?

Comment: @Mandroid : I have updated the answer. The entity should be the entity that corresponds to the result.

Comment: @Mandroid: Did it work for you? How did you solved it?